# SignalR on multiple application pools

Tags: asp.net, signalr, application-pool

I am trying to send notifications to specific clients from server about transaction changes. I'm doing well so far in local and development environment, but in LIVE we have 3 app pools (3 physical servers) with loadbalancer (all three have same machine key).

So it looks like when notification is triggered server side on same pool the client is connected - it works, but doesn't work if pools are different.

Can anyone suggest how to deal with this - or maybe the problem is in bad code (incorrect hub context handling or something). I'm new to SignalR - so used examples for message broadcasting from SignalR documentation.

Here is mu hub:

```
public class ExampleClassHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ExampleClass _ExampleClassInstance;
    public ExampleClassHub() : this(ExampleClass.Instance) { }

    public ExampleClassHub(ExampleClass ExampleClassInstance)
    {
        _ExampleClassInstance = ExampleClassInstance;
    }
}
```

Here is the class which serves static instance:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private readonly static Lazy<ExampleClass> _instance = new Lazy<ExampleClass>(() =>
        new ExampleClass(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ExampleClassHub>().Clients));

    private IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> Clients { get; set; }

    private ExampleClass(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
    {
        Clients = clients;
    }

    public static ExampleClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    public void NotifyTransactionChange(int userId, string tid, bool isTransactionSuccessfull)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Notification { UserId = userId, Tid = tid, IsTransactionSuccessful = isTransactionSuccessfull });
        Clients.User(userId.ToString()).notifyTransactionStateChange(json);
    }


    class Notification
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Tid { get; set; }
        public bool IsTransactionSuccessful { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So from server-side notification is triggered the following way:

```
ExampleClass.Instance.NotifyTransactionChange(...)
```

Comment: this might help http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: @JAG..., thanks - solved it using SQL-Server Backplane

Comment: @RUKAclMortality Just an FYI, Microsoft recommends using Redis as the backplane (obviously SQL Server and Service Bus backplanes have their place as well)

Comment: @Mark C. Thanks for the insight. Since we're only interested in server broadcast - we'll do fine with SQL Server backplane right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using SignalR scaleout:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr